# Pass variable value through nested if() statements - PHP

Tags: php

I want to be able to do the below but unable to since the values are not passed to the next `if` statement.

```
if(something){
  $x=SomeValue;
    if(something){
      $y=SomeValue;
       if($x==$y){
         echo"x & y matches";
       }
     }
}
```

I also tried `$GLOBALS` in the respective `if` statements but still doesn't work.

How do I pass the values of `$x` & `$y` to the third `if()` statement

**Actual code**

```
if($i%2) {
        $dx1 = $row['sec1'];
        echo $dx1;
        if($i%2==0){
            $dx2 = $row['sec2'];
            echo $dx2;
            if($dx1==$dx2){echo $dx1." do not match ".$dx2;}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you conditions ("`something`" in your code)? Sounds like that's where your issue is.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Whatever values you set for $x and $y will absolutely be available throughout the code as shown. Maybe show us the actual code instead of this?

Comment: @Qirel conditions can be anything and can be checked if met with a "echo"

Comment: Can you show your *actual* conditions, and how they are defined? Without it, it's hard to say. Because [**the code works**](https://3v4l.org/vkXf3).

Comment: @Qirel q updated

Comment: @bobblebubble why wont it work for me!?

Comment: Your conditions $i%2 and $i%2== 0 are totally differents and one is the opposite of the other, so you'll never go inside the second if

Comment: If $i%2 is true, it evaluates to anything but 0, thus $i%2 cannot equal 0 in your second if statement if it also satisfies your first if statement

Comment: @yoeunes $i%2 is always true & $i%2==0 also fires.  
@ Qirel both of them are records from db

Comment: @yanman1234  $i%2 is like even / odd

Comment: [**See this live demo**](https://3v4l.org/WBuul) and you'll see. One is truthy, one is false. They are never the same.

Comment: @X10nD No, $i%2 is not *like* anything, it *is* either 1 or 0 however. Evaluating to 0 makes your first if false, evaluating to 1 passes your first if but makes your second if false. You simply cannot evaluate true in both statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP, any value which is *not* "empty" is considered "truthy"; in the case of an integer, that means `0` is false, and everything else is true. So `if($i%2)` means the same as `if( $i % 2 != 0 )`.

Later, you nest *inside* that `if` a similar-looking condition, `if($i%2==0)`, which is actually *the exact opposite*. To reach the inner `if`, you have to first have gone into the outer `if`, so both conditions need to be true to reach the innermost code.

As you say, the conditions are equivalent to "$i is odd" and "$i is even". To get into the first if statement, `$i` must be odd; but to get into the second, it must *also* be even. No value of `$i` will ever meet both conditions, so the innermost code will never be reached.

Comment: If either one of the if() fire then $dx1 or $dx2 must echo in the third if?

Comment: @X10nD No, you cannot reach the second `if` unless the first `if` evaluates to true. If `$i` is even, the entire block of code will be skipped by the first `if`.